# Using functions how to split a string by coma "," and remove single space space and if 2 consecutive occurs replace it with single.

Tags: python, string

I have a question that ask the user to input a string `THE` and split it as three different string, output like this `T,H,E` I tried but output same with input.

```
def func():
str1=input("Enter String : ")
','.split(str1)
print(str1)

func()
```

Output

```
THE
```

And second question is that ask the user to enter a string `T H E  S T R I N G` and the output should `THE STRING` when one space occurs remove it and if more then one then replace it whit single space.
Here is my code.

```
def func2():
str2=input("Enter String :")
for i in str2:
    if(i.isspace==True):
        del(i)
    else:
        str2=str2+i
print(str2)
func2()
```

output is.

```
T H E  S T R I N GTHESTRING
```

I have no idea how to correct it.

Comment: Wrong way round and doesn't assign the result back to anything if it did work: `','.split(str1)`. Use `str1 = str1.split(',')`

Comment: ^ is a more-general case. You actually just want to call `list()` on the input to split it into individual characters then `join()` the characters back together with a comma delimiter.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  In particular, you can have only one question per posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store the value after splitting and not printing it.
Just change `','.split(str1)` with `str1 =str1.split(',')` and print `str1`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for the `split` method: it doesn't apply to your first problem at all.  Instead, the solution is much simpler: take the individual characters and `join` them with commas:

```
char_list = list(str1)
str2 = ','.join(char_list)
```

... and print or return str3.  Yes, this can be shortened; I'm teaching you the individual steps.

As the posting guidelines tell you, each question must have a separate posting.  I'll leave the other answer for your other posting.

Answer (score 0):

There's a distinction between in-place and standard operators. In-place functions actually change in the input, while standard operators give a result as output, and that output then has to be assigned or passed to something else for it to be used. (Also, you don't have the syntax correct; it should be `'str1.split(',')`) The `split` operator is a standard operator; `'str1.split(',')` doesn't affect the value of `str1`, but instead creates a new result. Since you're not doing anything with that result, it gets thrown away. You could do `split_string ='str1.split(',')` and then `print(new_string)` or just `print('str1.split(',')`.

Also, the problem statements "split it as three different string" and "output like this T,H,E" are contradictory.  If you want a list of three strings, that would be `['T','H','E']`. Saying you want an output of `T,H,E` makes it sound like you want a single string with commas between the letters.